# Azure offline update issue at the android

Tags: android, database, azure, offline

I'm trying to follow the sample project named "TodoOffline" which is provided by Microsoft Azure.
There is feature to update the table fields "text" and I couldn't see the working even I changed the "text" field several times.

I had checked the databases at the azure dashboard, there is new created item without changing of "text" field.

Do u have anyone has same situation with sample project?

Sample project link is following.
https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/TodoOffline/Android

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before but it was an error of the SDK's version. What i've done was add `__delete` to the `MobileServiceSyncTable` Schema (and increase the database's version number when creating the SQLiteLocalStore) like this:

```
    tableDefinition.put("__deleted", ColumnDataType.Boolean);
```

However, they fixed this problem on the recent version(2.0.2 Beta). Check it here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/18/mobile-services-beta-android-sdk-with-offline-incremental-sync-soft-delete-and-android-studio-migration/

PS: the new version doesn't have the class `MobileServicePreconditionFailedExceptionBase` used on the `ConflictResolver`. If you download the new version, move the content of the if in the line 404 to the `catch(throwable e)` block in line 401.